# How to resize chart sheets in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

To be clear, I'm not asking how to resize charts ON a worksheet, but how to resize Charts that ARE worksheets.

I want to resize the chart to be 3.79cm high and 5.91 wide.

Though I have done this in the past already, I'm currently at a loss of how I did it. I've been trying and playing around with the code below:

```
Sub qqq()
Dim x

With Chart6
    .ChartArea.Height = 379.03
    .ChartArea.Width = 591.03
End With

End Sub
```

When I try to run it I get "Run Time Error 5"

What am I missing/not seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the input for `Height` and `Width` are in **points** and not in mm!

Using [this converter](http://www.asknumbers.com/CentimetersToPointsConversion.aspx) (1 Centimeter = 28.346... Points) or the built-in function `CentimetersToPoints` :

```
Sub qqq()
Dim x

With Chart6
    .ChartArea.Height = 107.3
    .ChartArea.Width = 167.5
    .ChartArea.Height = CentimetersToPoints(3.79)
    .ChartArea.Width = CentimetersToPoints(5.91)
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I think VBA has a built in CentimetersToPoints method, if you don't want to do the conversion.

Comment: Yes indeed, I wasn't sure that it was a built in function so I didn't included it, but I will correct this now! ;)

Comment: I managed to find yet a different way to adjust the height... though not a code solution. Simply adjust the Margins in the Page Setup properties. This got me to where I needed to go. I'll accept your answer as the right one as I was asking for a code solution though.

Comment: @rohrl77 : Hehe! ;) Sure, no problem but I'm still not sure that it will avoid your error... I haven't used charts in that depth for quite some time so I'm not sure how the areas are placed by I know there is also the plotarea and the shape, is it possible that the shape is too small to handle such a "big" chartarea? But as you are in chart worksheet, I guess there isn't a shape...

Comment: @rohrl77 : Just saw your comment, glad you found a solution! And thanks for accepting my answer! ;)

Comment: I had to use something like this `.ChartArea.Width = Application.CentimetersToPoints(16.35)`

Comment: Built-in CentimeterToPoints method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.centimeterstopoints